Virsh not assigning dynamic IP address for VM
I am trying to setup a KVM maschine on a Debian 12 host which is attached to the default network created by libvirt. However, even though the network is active and available on 192.168.122.1/24...
# ip addr show virbr0
55: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:16:d4:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

...there is no IP address assigned to the VM (i.e. the output of virsh net-dhcp-leases is empty).
The truncated output of virsh dumpxml vm0 is the following.
<domain type='kvm' id='5'>
...
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:ab:71:69'/>
      <source network='default' portid='8ff73a58-1d26-460a-81e9-94f3143e9006' bridge='virbr0'/>
      <target dev='vnet4'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
...
</domain>

The dumped XML of the default network is.
<network connections='1'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>e9f0c964-b736-4c6f-826f-0845a952f8ec</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:16:d4:1a'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

I already tried to track the issue with journalctl, but without success.

Test network connectivity
Test whether or not the vm has connectivity when you assign a static address. Log in on the virtual machine console and assign an address to the interface (I'm going to assume it's called eth0, but replace that with whatever is appropriate if it's different):
ip addr add 192.168.122.100/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up

Make sure you use an address that isn't already in use by another vm.
This obviously requires that you are able to log in on the vm console; if you haven't previously set a password that would allow you to do so, there are a variety solutions available (mounting the filesystem locally, using tools like guestfish or virt-customize, etc).
Now, see if you can ping the bridge:
ping 192.168.122.1

Does that work or not?
Check that the network is up
Ensure that the associated network has been started. Do you see the default network in the output of virsh net-list?
Check that dnsmasq is running
When you start a libvirt network, libvirtd starts up a dnsmasq instance to manage address allocation for that network. For the default network, you should see something like this in the output of ps -fe:
dnsmasq   252591       1  0 Mar29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper

If dnsmaq is not running, then you can try to reset the network:

Shut down the vm.
Run virsh net-destroy default
Run virsh net-start default
Start the vm

Then see if the situation has changed.
